# Option to Enable/Disable Right Click

Tags: excel, vba, menu, hide

I want to limit people viewing hidden parts of my excel. To still allow my VBA to hide/unhide columns/sheets as the user clicks through the file I've opted not to protect the workbook structure. The below code works, but I want to put a button in to a hidden sheet to disable this macro if a user knows that it is there (i.e. I want some users to have full control, without having to go change the VBA) - any ideas?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    MsgBox ("Sorry Right Click is Disbaled for this Workbook")
End Sub
```

Thanks,

James

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4291-excel-disable-right-click-menu.html#a2)?

Comment: This is the same as the code in my question - what I'd like to build on is to give a macro option button to disable this functionality/some way to enable and disable this without entering VBA code directly

Comment: Ops, sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

you could place an ActiveX checkbox in the worksheet and use this in your sheet's module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If CheckBox1 Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Sorry Right Click is Disbaled for this Workbook")
    End If
End Sub
```